# PHP/Mysqli check before update

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hey I am completely new to PHP/MySqli, I would like to check before update if Scanstatus field of given ID is already "Scanned". if its already Scanned display a message as "Already Scanned" else Update.

Below code only update and doesn't check if already exists.

```
<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "passwd","dbname"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "failed to connect " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{

    $query = "UPDATE `sales` SET `ScanStatus` = 'Scanned' WHERE `id` = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query); 

    if (!$result) {
    die('Error' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Successfully updated";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQLInjections attacks, as you are still learning about PHP & MySQL please take a quick look at [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this code:

Use `if(mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) > 0 )` or no comparison at all.

Replace your code with this:

```
<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "passwd","dbname"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "failed to connect " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{

    $my_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `id` = ". $id . " AND `ScanStatus` = 'Scanned'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($my_query) > 0){
        echo "Already ScanStatus is Scanned";
    }
    else{
        $query = "UPDATE `sales` SET `ScanStatus` = 'Scanned' WHERE `id` = ".$id;
        //echo $query;die;
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query); 

        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0 ){
           echo "Successfully updated";

           /* get new updated data */
           $new_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `sales` WHERE `id` = '$id' LIMIT 1");
           $new_info = mysqli_fetch_array($new_query);
           echo "<pre>"; print_r($new_info);

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not updated";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you really tried your answer? It doesn't check for ID in select query and also is checking the wrong condition.

Comment: You are firing a `SELECT` query and where are you fetching the result? What's the point of doing a `SELECT`?

Comment: You have mentioned to use `mysqli_affected_rows`, where have you used it?

Comment: No check it's fine.

Comment: Excellent ...This works perfect...but if I enter a id which doesnt exist in the database ...it shows Successfully updated....also if i can after successfully scanned i can show full details of that given user id (name, Scan status, mobile)

Comment: Perfect...Thank You...Last thing How i can design it atleast in table form in HTML. as its coming in array ...weird form. Thank U Once Again

Answer (score 0):

Try following php code

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "passwd","dbname"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "failed to connect " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

else{
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
{
 $sql = "UPDATE sales SET ScanStatus = 'Scanned' WHERE id = '$id'";
      $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

              echo "Successfully updated";

      } else {
        die('Error' . mysqli_error($connection));
      }
}
}
```

When click SUBMIT button "isset($_POST['Submit'])" will be true and direct into if statement. then run sql command and is if there is any result that sql query affected go into next if statement after true the condition "$result->num_rows > 0" then echo "Successfully updated".

Comment: "Try".. You need to explain what changes have you done? Why? Reason.. so that everyone understands. If you want OP to try, than better use comments and not answers.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to update only if the `ScanStatus` field is not `Scanned`

So you can modify you existing query like this without the need to fetch the record:

```
$query = "UPDATE `sales` SET `ScanStatus` = 'Scanned' WHERE `id` = $id AND `ScanStatus` != 'Scanned'";
```

Just change the query to above and use:

`if(mysqli_affected_rows($result) > 0 ){`

Here is a full code:

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "passwd","dbname"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "failed to connect " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))  {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "UPDATE `sales` SET `ScanStatus` = 'Scanned' WHERE `id` = $id AND `ScanStatus` != 'Scanned'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0 ){
        echo "Successfully updated";
    }
    else {
        echo 'Already Scanned';
    }
}
```

Comment: What error is it throwing? And hope you are checking the `$id` for which `ScanStatus` != 'Scanned'

Comment: Please give me complete example as i am a beginner. may be i am missing something.

Comment: where's the message "Already Scanned" also when i run your above code it gives me this error Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in on line 13
Successfully updated

Comment: That warning means, its expecting a connection parameter which `$connection`. Just made that update, you can try it now.

Comment: It doesn't check for ID. I mean it doesnt verify the ID in the databse. even if i put a random number it shows Already Scanned